# Error :Stack around the variable 'hexStr' was corrupted in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want use AES Algorithm.

I use this function on it

```
void SubBytes(char *SArr[4][4]){
int r,c;
char xlook[2];char ylook[2]; char hexStr[2]; char *Pad;
int intxlook,intylook;
char *temp;
int subbyte;
Pad = (char *)malloc (sizeof(char));
temp = (char *)malloc (sizeof(char));

for (r = 0; r < 4; r++)
  for(c = 0; c < 4; c++){
        strcpy(temp,"");
        strcpy(xlook,"");strcpy(ylook,"");
        strcpy(temp,SArr[r][c]);
        xlook[0] = temp[0]; xlook[1] = '\0';
        ylook[0] = temp[1];ylook[1] = '\0';
        intxlook = string_to_dec(xlook);
        intylook = string_to_dec(ylook);

     subbyte = SBox(intxlook,intylook);
     itoa(subbyte,hexStr,16);

     if (strlen(hexStr) < 2){
        strcpy(Pad,"");
        Pad = Padding(0,1);
        strcat(Pad,hexStr);  
        strcpy(SArr[r][c],Pad);
     }
     else
        strcpy(SArr[r][c],hexStr);

  }

  //free(temp); free(Pad);
}     //end
```

but i get error

**Stack around the variable 'hexStr' was corrupted in c**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to null-terminate `hexStr`.

So when you do `strcpy(SArr[r][c],hexStr);`. it will attempt to copy into `SArr[r][c]` from `hexStr` until it reaches a `'\0'`, which could be anywhere.

Comment: @ar.gorgin increase size by 1 and set the last char to `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

`temp` has enough space for a single character:

```
temp = (char *)malloc (sizeof(char));
```

meaning this will overrun the end of the buffer and a probable cause for the corruption:

```
strcpy(temp,SArr[r][c]);
```

As this is C++, use `std::string` instead of `char*`.